# How can fitting line help in data visualisation of mpg dataset while comparing displacement of engine with highway mileage of the cars in R software

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am interested in knowing about the possibility of using fitting line in R software data visualisation of mpg dataset available in ggplot2 package

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim from the ggplot2's `geom_smooth()` documentation:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>